# Need a way to integrate an Invert function(Check All/Uncheck All) through radio buttons - for the Checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

Am relatively new to what I am doing here. I am just putting together stuff with what I find here and other open resources.

The problem I am having is - With the current setup a person can choose a radio button and check a couple boxes and goto the other radio button option and choose boxes under that. I am trying to get the Checkboxes to be All Checked when someone selects the radion option and UncheckALL when the person chooses another option on the radio button group.

So if I select option 'a' under 'GENERAL' and then goto 'DETAILED' - 'a' should be unchecked.

Heres the code I am using in [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljm8y3pd/)

HTML:

```
<div id="RadioWidget">
<label><input type="radio" name="chkboxs" value="General" />General Clean</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="chkboxs" value="Detailed" />Detailed Clean</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="chkboxs" value="Commercial" />Commercial Clean</label>
</div>
<div id="General" class="desc">
<p class="maintextBlue">General
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="GeneralOptn[]" value="a" />a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="GeneralOptn[]" value="b" />b</label>
</p>
</div>
<div id="Detailed" class="desc">
<p class="maintextBlue">Detailed
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="DetailedOptn[]" value="a" />a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="DetailedOptn[]" value="b" />b</label>
</p>
</div>
<div id="Commercial" class="desc">
<p class="maintextBlue">Commercial
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="CommercialOptn[]" value="a" />a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="CommercialOptn[]" value="b" />b</label>
</p>
</div>
```

Jscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='chkboxs']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

This was a piece of script I found that inverts the checkbox state. But not sure how to integrate it to the radio button. this snippet was working off a onClick() fn for a button.

```
$("A[href='#invert_selection']").click( function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr('rel') + " INPUT[type='checkbox']").each( function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
return false;
});
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this requires you to add IDS to your input fields... but it would work. 
If you want to control multiple input fields you can always uses classes to..

```js
jQuery("#generalA").click(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
    // is checked do some stuff if you want
  }else{
    // is mot checked uncheck the checkbox with an ID of #detailedA
    jQuery('#detailedA').prop('checked', false); 
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes. If it does not work i will modify the code. if it does please accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The above response by AndrewMac helped. 
I just had to figure out a way it helped my existing setup.
Below is the small addition I did to get the desired setup - this way it actually disables all the unnecessary inputs thereby eliminated from the final send out of the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.desc").hide().find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);;
$("input[name$='chkboxs']").click(function() {
var test = $(this).val();
$("div.desc").hide().find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);;
$("#" + test).show().find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', false);;
});
});
```

I have also updated the same on my fiddle page. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljm8y3pd/)
Thanks for the help AndrewMac - Sorry for the long time to post this response/answer.